# Azure data factory: From Salesforce to REST API

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created data factory source as Salesforce for which i am querying lead and then want to pass each lead email id as an argument (POST request) to a REST endpoint.

I am not sure in the pipeline what sink should i put and if it is HTTP File dataset then how to pass the email id from Source to sink in the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how to surface data in ADF itself is through a lookup activity. You can then iterate through the results of the lookup using a forEach activity. Reference the result of the lookup using in the ForEach items parameter:

```
@activity('nameoflookupactivity').output.value
```

If you need to add multiple IDs at once I think to only way would be to concatenate your IDs in a sink like a SQL database. You would first have to copy your IDs to a table in SQL. Then in Azure SQL DB/SQL server 2017 you could use the following query:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG([salesforce_Id], ',') AS Ids FROM salesforceLeads;
```

The ADF tutorial for incrementally loading multiple tables discusses the ForEach activity extensively, you can find it here:
[ADF Incrementally Loading multiple Tables Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-powershell)

For more information about the STRING_AGG function check out:[STRING_AGG Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Thanks,

Jan

Comment: Data factory has string functions on its own, you can use CONCAT as a way to concatenate. More here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#string-functions

Comment: Yes but I don't think you can dynamically CONCAT an array with a seprator which would be the case when pulling a list of Ids